# How do I add a column to a 2d array with specific dtype?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is the code I wrote. The 'guteliste25.txt' contains a data table with a header where the names of the colums are specified.

```
import numpy as np
d = 'guteliste25.txt'
CNS = np.genfromtxt(d, dtype = None, names = True)

dt = np.dtype([('R','<f8')])
test = np.ones(len(CNS),dtype=dt)
klaus = np.concatenate((CNS,test), axis=1)
```

The error it spits out in the last line is:
TypeError: expected a readable buffer object

I think it must be some problem with np.genfromtxt and its formatting of the different rows.

I just want to add one value to each row, i.e. in total one column and have a name for it to so that I can access it easily via: CNS['R']

Answer (score 0):

Its probably best to create a structured array from scratch and fill it:

The two examples begin with:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib import recfunctions

ints = np.ones(5,dtype=np.int)
floats = np.ones(5,dtype=np.float)
strings = np.array(['A']*5)
```

To create an empty structured array and then fill it with values:

```
out=np.empty(5,dtype=[('ints', '>i4'), ('floats', '>f8'), ('strings', '|S4')])

out['ints']=ints
out['floats']=floats
out['strings']=strings

print out
[(1, 1.0, 'A') (1, 1.0, 'A') (1, 1.0, 'A') (1, 1.0, 'A') (1, 1.0, 'A')]

print out.dtype
[('ints', '>i4'), ('floats', '>f8'), ('strings', 'S4')]
```

To append data to a current array:

```
out=np.lib.recfunctions.append_fields(ints,['floats','strings'],[floats,strings])

print out
[(1, 1.0, 'A') (1, 1.0, 'A') (1, 1.0, 'A') (1, 1.0, 'A') (1, 1.0, 'A')]

print out.dtype #note the name applied to the first array
[('f0', '>i4'), ('floats', '>f8'), ('strings', 'S4')]
```

I highly recommend [python pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) for dealing with structured arrays.

Comment: Hi Ophion, thank you for your Reply! It is right and helpful.
I cannot vote for it though.